# PHP send email using FOREACH div on the page?

Tags: php, jquery, email

I am doing a kind of contact form where the user can add as many time as he want a `div` that contains 3 things: 1 select box, and 2 text boxes.

I would like to know how its possible to select all boxes and add it into a nice PHP email function to send it clean like this:

```
Select1
Textbox1
Textbox1-1

select2
textbox2
textbox2-2
```

For more information on how I proceed, look below:

I use Jquery to clone my current box that contains the 3 elements, using this line:

```
$('#element_1').clone().attr('id', 'element_' + ++counter).appendTo('.container');
```

And then I change every element inside this box with jQuery again with the `.attr()` function. Every element has its own ID, following an easy pattern of `+1` to everyone of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the counter. That makes it difficult to access in php. Use an array for your input's name instead.

Example:

```
<select name="selectbox[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input name="textbox[]" />
<input name="textbox2[]" />

<select name="selectbox[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input name="textbox[]" />
<input name="textbox2[]" />
```

php:

```
foreach( $_POST['textbox'] as $i => $textbox ) {
    // use $i as the key to get other inputs

    $textbox2 = $_POST['textbox2'][$i];
    $select = $_POST['selectbox'][$i];

    // 1 entire set of inputs
    echo $select;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $textbox;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $textbox2;
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: I've tried using exactly what you sent me there, but it gives me an error on line 12 where you close the bracket. (I took the code, added it in a php file to see if it works)

Comment: I know _exactly_ what the problem is, but I'm hesitant to point it out. Stackoverflow is about helping, not spoonfeeding. Look at the code and see if you can figure out my mistake. I'll correct the answer in 15 minutes.

Comment: I beleive somone forgot to close an echo :) .. >> since i use rarely PHP, how could i add my select boxes into this bloc of code ?

Comment: You got it! I'll edit the code with select boxes in there too.

Answer (score 1):

What's the real problem? Just be sure that all the div blocks are cloned into `<form></form>` tag and they will proceed to server side on form submit. If you are struggling with a question how to process those input fields, then use [] brackets for inputs name, so they will come to your script as an array and you can loop through them. ( example: `input name="name[]"`)

Comment: Hmm, haven't tought about arrays. How would you actually use an array from an HTML page and send it to the PHP form method ?